# Problems with urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I'm pretty new to Python and coding, so keep that in mind.

I'm making a slack bot that shorten urls.

But I have some problems with the urllib encoding.

This is the kind of link I'm encoding:

```
https://flaf.net/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-15m,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:[logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD,interval:auto,query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*83095952')),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))
```

i use `urllib.quote(url)`

and it returns me something like this:

```
https://flaf.net/app/kibana%23/discover%3F_g%3D%28refreshInterval%3A%28display%3AOff%2Cpause%3A%21f%2Cvalue%3A0%29%2Ctime%3A%28from%3Anow-15m%2Cmode%3Aquick%2Cto%3Anow%29%29%26amp%3B_a%3D%28columns%3A%21%28_source%29%2Cindex%3A%5Blogstash-%5DYYYY.MM.DD%2Cinterval%3Aauto%2Cquery%3A%28query_string%3A%28analyze_wildcard%3A%21t%2Cquery%3A%27%2A86625627%27%29%29%2Csort%3A%21%28%27%40timestamp%27%2Cdesc%29%29
```

And that look all fine BUT it if you put it in a browser it have replaced 
`&_a=` form the original link to `&amp;_a=` and that breaks the link.

I have tried with:

```
urllib2
urllib.quote(url.encode("utf-8"))
urllib2.quote(url.encode("utf-8"))
```

and it's all the same.

Some ideas to fix it, or what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: I do not think I understand your question?

i have this in the post 

I have tried with:

urllib2 - 

urllib.quote(url.encode("utf-8")) -

urllib2.quote(url.encode("utf-8")) -

Comment: The documentation says [**`urllib.quote`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) is intended for quoting the path section of the URL by default. However, you could try passing a parameter `safe='/&'`.